# Create Athena table using s3 source data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

Below is given the s3 path where I have stored the files obtained at the end of a process. The below-provided path is dynamic, that is, the value of the following fields will vary - partner_name, customer_name, product_name.

```
s3://bucket/{val1}/data/{val2}/output/intermediate_results
```

I am trying to create Athena tables for each output file present under **output/** as well as under **intermediate_results/** directories, for each val1-val2.

> Each file is a CSV.

But I am not much familiar with AWS Athena so I'm unable to figure out the way to implement this. I would really appreciate any kind of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html). You will need to specify the `LOCATION` of the data in Amazon S3 by providing a **path**.

Amazon Athena will automatically use all files in that path, including subdirectories. This means that a table created with a Location of `output/` will include all subdirectories, including `intermediate_results`. Therefore, your data storage format is **not compatible with your desired use for Amazon Athena**. You would need to put the data into separate paths for each table.